# HP Mini 210 -> No wireless networks detected after installing Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, netbook

What could possibly going wrong here? I recently acquired an HP Mini 210 with Windows 7 Starter. Since I have a licensed enterprise edition, I formatted the machine and put enterprise on it. Then, I installed the drivers here:

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareList?os=4062&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=4093637

For whatever reason, even after installing the drivers, I can't detect any wireless connections (whereas I could before). What could be going wrong?

Comment: No other help? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too. I definately think there were missing drivers or something...

Anyway, I managed to get around it by using hp recovery to revert to the starter edition. Then i used the 'Windows Anytime Upgrade' feature, put in my Win7 Pro key and it upgraded, keeping all the drivers in tact, and now the wireless works in Pro edition.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is the adapter visible in network connections?
2. Have you accidentally knocked the wireless on/off switch on the outside of the case?

Comment: Yes and no. Oddly enough, on restart, the networks visible flicker but then disappear.

Comment: This is absurd. I'm installing ubuntu.